When attempting to run the container in Docker, in combination with Poetry, the global interpreter is being used
I'm encountering an issue with my Docker setup where it appears that the virtual environment is not being used correctly, causing the django module not to be found. Here are the relevant details:
My Dockerfile
FROM python:3.12
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* /app/
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:${PATH}"
COPY . /app/
RUN ls -la /app/
RUN poetry install --no-dev
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create true \
    && poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
RUN ls -l /app/.venv/bin/ && which python
RUN /app/.venv/bin/pip list
RUN /app/.venv/bin/python -m django --version
RUN poetry run python -m django --version
RUN poetry run python3 weather_app/manage.py migrate
RUN poetry run python3 weather_app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
RUN ls -la /app/.venv/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["poetry", "run", "python", "weather_app/manage.py"]
CMD ["runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]

My docker-compose
version: '3.8'
services:
  weather:
    image: weather
    build: .
    command: /app/.venv/bin/python weather_app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

My pyproject.toml
[tool.poetry]
name = "weather-app"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Cur1yB <alexandr.ignatev1996@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.12"
django = "^5.0.7"
requests = "^2.32.3"
djangorestframework = "^3.15.2"


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

When I build and run the Docker container, I get the following error:
>>> make docker-up

docker-compose up --build
[+] Building 12.6s (20/20) FINISHED                                                                           docker:desktop-linux
 => [weather internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 734B                                                                                          0.0s
 => [weather internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                               0.0s
 => [weather internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.12                                                        1.0s
 => [weather  1/15] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.12@sha256:b6f142bd70d2219c98c143094ad2a0b8cc882294a7fb2664377a7b68edfc57  0.0s
 => [weather internal] load build context                                                                                     0.1s
 => => transferring context: 87.81kB                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [weather  2/15] WORKDIR /app                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [weather  3/15] COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* /app/                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [weather  4/15] RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -                                        0.0s
 => [weather  5/15] COPY . /app/                                                                                              0.3s
 => [weather  6/15] RUN ls -la /app/                                                                                          0.4s
 => [weather  7/15] RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false                                                                0.7s
 => [weather  8/15] RUN poetry install --no-ansi                                                                              6.2s
 => [weather  9/15] RUN ls -l /app/.venv/bin/ && which python                                                                 0.2s
 => [weather 10/15] RUN /app/.venv/bin/pip list                                                                               0.5s
 => [weather 11/15] RUN /app/.venv/bin/python -m django --version                                                             0.3s
 => [weather 12/15] RUN poetry run python -m django --version                                                                 0.4s
 => [weather 13/15] RUN poetry run python3 weather_app/manage.py migrate                                                      1.2s
 => [weather 14/15] RUN poetry run python3 weather_app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput                                      0.7s
 => [weather 15/15] RUN ls -la /app/.venv/bin                                                                                 0.1s
 => [weather] exporting to image                                                                                              0.3s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                       0.3s
 => => writing image sha256:8d19d34d4230ad39d3a38e19c34f50c8333e6a49bb1902672fd9c740737e0dda                                  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/weather                                                                                    0.0s
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container weather_app-weather-1  Recreated                                                                                 0.1s 
Attaching to weather-1
weather-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
weather-1  |   File "/app/weather_app/manage.py", line 11, in main
weather-1  |     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
weather-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
weather-1  | 
weather-1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
weather-1  | 
weather-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
weather-1  |   File "/app/weather_app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
weather-1  |     main()
weather-1  |   File "/app/weather_app/manage.py", line 13, in main
weather-1  |     raise ImportError(
weather-1  | ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
weather-1 exited with code 1

Here is the detailed terminal output, where you can see (#14) that for some reason the global Python interpreter is used when starting.
docker build --progress=plain --no-cache . 
#0 building with "desktop-linux" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load .dockerignore
#1 transferring context: 2B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 transferring dockerfile: 734B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.12
#3 ...

#4 [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
#4 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.12
#3 DONE 4.1s

#5 [ 1/15] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.12@sha256:b6f142bd70d2219c98c143094ad2a0b8cc882294a7fb2664377a7b68edfc5767
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [ 2/15] WORKDIR /app
#6 CACHED

#7 [internal] load build context
#7 transferring context: 87.11kB 0.1s done
#7 DONE 0.1s

#8 [ 3/15] COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* /app/
#8 DONE 0.0s

#9 [ 4/15] RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
#9 0.997 Retrieving Poetry metadata
#9 1.946 
#9 1.953 # Welcome to Poetry!
#9 1.953 
#9 1.953 This will download and install the latest version of Poetry,
#9 1.953 a dependency and package manager for Python.
#9 1.953 
#9 1.953 It will add the `poetry` command to Poetry's bin directory, located at:
#9 1.953 
#9 1.953 /root/.local/bin
#9 1.953 
#9 1.953 You can uninstall at any time by executing this script with the --uninstall option,
#9 1.953 and these changes will be reverted.
#9 1.953 
#9 1.954 Installing Poetry (1.8.3)
#9 1.954 Installing Poetry (1.8.3): Creating environment
#9 12.10 Installing Poetry (1.8.3): Installing Poetry
#9 55.14 Installing Poetry (1.8.3): Creating script
#9 55.15 Installing Poetry (1.8.3): Done
#9 55.15 
#9 55.15 Poetry (1.8.3) is installed now. Great!
#9 55.15 
#9 55.15 To get started you need Poetry's bin directory (/root/.local/bin) in your `PATH`
#9 55.15 environment variable.
#9 55.15 
#9 55.15 Add `export PATH="/root/.local/bin:$PATH"` to your shell configuration file.
#9 55.15 
#9 55.15 Alternatively, you can call Poetry explicitly with `/root/.local/bin/poetry`.
#9 55.15 
#9 55.15 You can test that everything is set up by executing:
#9 55.15 
#9 55.15 `poetry --version`
#9 55.15 
#9 DONE 55.3s

#10 [ 5/15] COPY . /app/
#10 DONE 0.1s

#11 [ 6/15] RUN ls -la /app/
#11 0.106 total 68
#11 0.106 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Jul 19 02:58 .
#11 0.106 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Jul 19 03:11 ..
#11 0.106 drwxr-xr-x 7 root root  4096 Jul 18 10:14 .git
#11 0.106 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    98 Jul 18 10:04 .gitignore
#11 0.106 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Jul 19 02:54 .venv
#11 0.106 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   695 Jul 19 02:58 Dockerfile
#11 0.106 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   619 Jul 18 10:15 Makefile
#11 0.106 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root     0 Jul 18 16:52 README.md
#11 0.106 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   208 Jul 18 11:42 docker-compose.yml
#11 0.106 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19966 Jul 18 09:04 poetry.lock
#11 0.106 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   347 Jul 18 09:41 pyproject.toml
#11 0.106 drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Jul 18 05:23 tests
#11 0.106 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    37 Jul 18 08:57 users_for_test.txt
#11 0.106 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Jul 19 02:24 weather_app
#11 DONE 0.1s

#12 [ 7/15] RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
#12 DONE 0.5s

#13 [ 8/15] RUN poetry install --no-ansi
#13 0.367 Installing dependencies from lock file
#13 0.397 
#13 0.397 Package operations: 9 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
#13 0.397 
#13 0.397   - Installing asgiref (3.8.1)
#13 0.398   - Installing sqlparse (0.5.1)
#13 2.502   - Installing certifi (2024.7.4)
#13 2.503   - Installing charset-normalizer (3.3.2)
#13 2.505   - Installing django (5.0.7)
#13 2.509   - Installing idna (3.7)
#13 2.511   - Installing urllib3 (2.2.2)
#13 27.02   - Installing djangorestframework (3.15.2)
#13 27.02   - Installing requests (2.32.3)
#13 30.77 
#13 30.77 Installing the current project: weather-app (0.1.0)
#13 DONE 31.0s

#14 [ 9/15] RUN ls -l /app/.venv/bin/ && which python
#14 0.185 total 52
#14 0.185 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2258 Jul 19 02:49 activate
#14 0.185 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1517 Jul 19 02:49 activate.csh
#14 0.185 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3081 Jul 19 02:49 activate.fish
#14 0.185 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2765 Jul 19 02:49 activate.nu
#14 0.185 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1689 Jul 19 02:49 activate.ps1
#14 0.185 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1321 Jul 19 02:49 activate_this.py
#14 0.185 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  268 Jul 19 03:11 django-admin
#14 0.185 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  238 Jul 19 03:11 normalizer
#14 0.185 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  226 Jul 19 02:49 pip
#14 0.185 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  226 Jul 19 02:49 pip-3.12
#14 0.185 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  226 Jul 19 02:49 pip3
#14 0.185 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  226 Jul 19 02:49 pip3.12
#14 0.185 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Jul 19 02:49 python -> /usr/local/bin/python
#14 0.185 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    6 Jul 19 02:49 python3 -> python
#14 0.185 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    6 Jul 19 02:49 python3.12 -> python
#14 0.185 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  221 Jul 19 03:11 sqlformat
#14 0.186 /usr/local/bin/python
#14 DONE 0.2s

#15 [10/15] RUN /app/.venv/bin/pip list
#15 0.423 Package             Version  Editable project location
#15 0.423 ------------------- -------- -------------------------
#15 0.423 asgiref             3.8.1
#15 0.423 certifi             2024.7.4
#15 0.423 charset-normalizer  3.3.2
#15 0.423 Django              5.0.7
#15 0.423 djangorestframework 3.15.2
#15 0.424 idna                3.7
#15 0.424 pip                 24.1
#15 0.424 requests            2.32.3
#15 0.424 sqlparse            0.5.1
#15 0.424 urllib3             2.2.2
#15 0.424 weather-app         0.1.0    /app
#15 DONE 0.5s

#16 [11/15] RUN /app/.venv/bin/python -m django --version
#16 0.308 5.0.7
#16 DONE 0.3s

#17 [12/15] RUN poetry run python -m django --version
#17 0.527 5.0.7
#17 DONE 0.5s

#18 [13/15] RUN poetry run python3 weather_app/manage.py migrate
#18 0.937 Operations to perform:
#18 0.937   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, weather
#18 0.940 Running migrations:
#18 0.940   No migrations to apply.
#18 DONE 1.0s

#19 [14/15] RUN poetry run python3 weather_app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
#19 0.599 
#19 0.599 126 static files copied to '/app/weather_app/staticfiles'.
#19 DONE 0.7s

#20 [15/15] RUN ls -la /app/.venv/bin
#20 0.099 total 64
#20 0.099 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jul 19 03:11 .
#20 0.099 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jul 19 02:54 ..
#20 0.099 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2258 Jul 19 02:49 activate
#20 0.099 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1517 Jul 19 02:49 activate.csh
#20 0.099 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3081 Jul 19 02:49 activate.fish
#20 0.099 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2765 Jul 19 02:49 activate.nu
#20 0.099 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1689 Jul 19 02:49 activate.ps1
#20 0.099 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1321 Jul 19 02:49 activate_this.py
#20 0.099 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  268 Jul 19 03:11 django-admin
#20 0.099 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  238 Jul 19 03:11 normalizer
#20 0.099 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  226 Jul 19 02:49 pip
#20 0.099 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  226 Jul 19 02:49 pip-3.12
#20 0.099 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  226 Jul 19 02:49 pip3
#20 0.099 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  226 Jul 19 02:49 pip3.12
#20 0.099 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Jul 19 02:49 python -> /usr/local/bin/python
#20 0.099 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    6 Jul 19 02:49 python3 -> python
#20 0.099 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    6 Jul 19 02:49 python3.12 -> python
#20 0.099 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  221 Jul 19 03:11 sqlformat
#20 DONE 0.1s

#21 exporting to image
#21 exporting layers
#21 exporting layers 0.3s done
#21 writing image sha256:2dadf3ee954f521624f8bbc8a1fcff55f1db7e50a736cc17fd1d40019d9054cb done
#21 DONE 0.3s

I’m naturally going crazy because I haven’t been able to solve this problem for about 7-12 hours! ._.'

Out of curiosity, why do you need a virtual env inside a (python based) docker image?

It looks like your Dockerfile is creating a virtual environment in /app/.venv.  The Compose file then has a volumes: mount that hides everything in /app and replaces it with arbitrary content from the host system.  This includes hiding the virtual environment.
In the Compose file, delete the volumes: block.  You also do not need the command: override (and with the particular ENTRYPOINT construction in the Dockerfile it will cause problems).  You should be able to reduce the Compose file to just this:
version: '3.8'
services:
  weather:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

